# Where can I get large road distance matrix from?

Tags: google-api, distance, traveling-salesman, google-distancematrix-api, osrm

I need to get real distance matrix (taking roads on board) between 320 locations. I have the information about theirs geographic coordinates.

I'd like to use Google Distance Matrix Api but there are limits making my task impossible or if I divided matrix on small pieces it would take a long time.

I'm thinking about OSRM and my own routing server but it requires much effort.

What do you think about Google? Have any experience with OSRM. Or maybe you can recommend something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OSRM](http://project-osrm.org/) matrix is very quick (seconds for 300 locations) but it provides driving times only. To get distances you'll have to call regular route service for each pair of coordinates (hours).

Other self hosted alternatives are [GraphHopper](https://www.graphhopper.com/open-source/) (no matrix, repeated calls to route) and [Valhalla](https://github.com/valhalla/valhalla) (distance and time matrix).

If you have to prepare the matrix just once a pay-per-use matrix service could be a better option. Both GraphHopper and Valhalla's Mapzen provide one, check if your matrix size is supported and what the cost is.

Comment: Yes. I've tried OSRM and its very fast. I got durations for 400x400 matrix in less than 0.5s. It's what I needed. I use duration for cost function so it's enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [Distancematrix.ai](https://distancematrix.ai/product?utm_source=SFlow&utm_medium=Answer&utm_campaign=Dev_4). This is an alternative to Google Maps Distance Matrix API, but it has even more advantages.

Main features:

- Accounts for traffic conditions, traffic jams, and restrictions
- Distances are calculated to account for driving, walking, or bicycling
- Departure and arrival time option is used to build a forecast
- Unlimited matrix size
- Easy migration, you have just to switch endpoint

Disclaimer: I work at the company that creates the API.